# Como converter array Bidimensional para um array Único?

Tags: c#, array, console

Eu tenho a seguinte definição do *Array Bidimensional*:

```
int[,] arrayBidimensional = new int[3, 3]
{
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 },
    { 7, 8, 9 }
};
```

A variável acima, não tem um método `.ToArray()` para que o valor seja convertido para um array simples.

Como faço para converter esse array *bidimensional* para um `int[ ]` em vez de `int[,]` ? Existe uma forma *simples* de fazer isso?

Comment: A forma mais simples é percorrer as 2 dimensões do array (com um for), e atribuir os valores a um segundo array.

Comment: António Campos, podes exemplificar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer um cast.. não será o mais eficiente mas é simples:

```
int[] array1d = arrayBidimensional.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Na verdade, a eficiência é a maior possível, falando de complexidade. É a mesma eficiência do que o método da minha resposta. A única coisa que difere é ter alguma indireção a mais, são umas 2 chamadas a mais, uma tentativa de cast e, depois, um cast para cada item — que, sinceramente, não sei o que acontece, uma vez que o item já é do tipo que se tenta fazer o cast.

Answer (score 4):

O algoritmo é simples: percorrer o array e criar um novo unidimensional.

```
using System;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        int[,] arrayBidimensional = new int[3, 3]
        {
            { 1, 2, 3 },
            { 4, 5, 6 },
            { 7, 8, 9 }
        };

        var linhas = arrayBidimensional.GetLength(0);
        int colunas = arrayBidimensional.GetLength(1);
        var novoArray = new int[linhas * colunas];

        for(int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < colunas; j++) {
                var indice = colunas * i + j;          
                novoArray[indice] = arrayBidimensional[i, j];
                
                Console.WriteLine($"{indice} = {novoArray[indice]}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no Repl.it**](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso379520-v1)</sup>

Pensando melhor, o código acima ainda pode ser simplificado para

```
using System;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        int[,] arrayBidimensional = new int[3, 3]
        {
            { 1, 2, 3 },
            { 4, 5, 6 },
            { 7, 8, 9 }
        };

        var novoArray 
            = new int[arrayBidimensional.GetLength(0) * arrayBidimensional.GetLength(1)];

        int indice = 0;
        foreach(var item in arrayBidimensional) {
            novoArray[indice] = item;
            Console.WriteLine($"{indice} = {novoArray[indice]}");
            indice++;
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no Repl.it**](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso379520-v2)</sup>

Comment: se eu editar esse código do Repl.it essa alteração vai refletir no seu código ou a alteração é exclusiva para mim? Pergunto só por curiosidade, pois não ou vou fazer alteração nenhuma.

Comment: @AugustoVasques não altera, fica só pra quem editou.